# Analysis of a pruning algorithm for the Hamiltonian path problem

Tags: hamiltonian-paths

$Definition:$ A *disconnecting path* in a connected undirected graph $G$ is a path, deletion of which disconnects $G$ as shown in the illustration below.
[image]
Now consider the following algorithm to decide the hamiltonian path problem in G.
$Algorithm$
$\ \ \ \ Input:\  A\ connected\ undirected\ graph\ G$
$\ \ \ \ Output:\ Print\ Yes\ if\ G\ has\ a\ hamiltonian\ path$
$\ \ \ \ x : A\ random\ vertex\ in\ G$
$\ \ \ \ P: A\ path\ in\ G,\ initially,\ P=<x>$
$\ \ \ \ P.s,\ P.e: Start\ and\ endpoint\ of\ P\ respectively$
$\ \ \ \ DECIDE\_HAMPATH(P)$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 1.\ if\ |P| = n-1$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 2. \ \ \ \ print\ Yes\ and\ terminate $
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 3. \ for\ v\ in\ neighbourhood(P.e)$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 4. \ \ \ \ if\ v∉P $
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 5. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ if\ P.append(x)\ is\ not\ a\ disconnecting\ path$
$\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ 6. \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ DECIDE \_HAMPATH(P.append(x))$

The intuition behind this algorithm is that if a partial path $P$ disconnects the graph, it means there is no way to span all vertices by extending $P$ because from $P.e$ we can only extend $P$ in any one of the components rendering other components unreachable. This way we can preemptively know if a partial path $P$ will ever grow to a hamiltonian path and choose not to explore this path any further and prune the unfruitful search space rooted at the endpoint of $P$.

$Question:$ What is the worst case time complexity of this algorithm ? Is it better than $O(2^n)$ ?